# EF ways to save complex class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, type-conversion

I try save complex class inside another class. TypeMask contained inside Entity. TypeMask overloads ToString method, and when time to save Entity comes, a want automaticaly save Mask prop in string form, and when I need load Entity class back automaticaly convert this string to TypeMask(constructor of TypeMask can build TypeMask using string). So what have I overload or from what have I inherit to make it real?

```
public class Entity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public TypeMask Mask { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do this:

```
public class Entity
{
    private TypeMask _typeMask;

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string TypeMaskString { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public TypeMask Mask
    { 
        get
        {
            if (this._typeMask == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(TypeMaskString))
            {
                this._typeMaks = new TypeMask(this.TypeMaskString);
                // Or some other way to create a TypeMask from string.
            }
            return this._typeMask;
        } 
        set
        {
            this._typeMask = value;
            this.TypeMaskString = value.ToString();
        } 
    }
}
```

There are some things to keep in mind here. When your code makes modifications to a `TypeMask` object you have to set the object again to update `TypeMaskString`. Of course, this is error-prone and elaborate, so you want to make sure that `TypeMask` can be modified through only one method (maybe a method in `Entity`).

The alternative is to have a property like this (skipping null checks for brevity)

```
public string TypeMaskString
{ 
    get
    {
        return this.TypeMask.ToString();
    } 
    set
    {
        this.TypeMask = new TypeMask(this.TypeMaskString);
    } 
}
```

Now the `TypeMask` object can be modified and `TypeMaskString` will always return an up-to-date value. But this may hit performance because it potentially converts `TypeMask` to and from string many times. More often than you may suspect, because EF's change tracker will always read `TypeMaskString` when it executes `DetectChanges`, which is a process that runs repeatedly.